# Find probability of a Poisson process.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random

Given that $N=\{N(t)\mid t\geq 0\}$ is a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda>0$

I need to find $P(N(3)=2\mid N(1)=0, N(5)=4)$

So this is a conditional probability (can anyone clarify if this is correct) and I assume that the mass function for a Poisson process is:

$p(N(t)=k)=e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$

But if I think in the way $P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$, I get wrong answer (the answer should not depend on $\lambda$).

Can anyone clarify how this calculation should be done? (note my coursebook is extremely abstract with no examples whatsoever) :(

Comment: Please post the steps of your calculation, the approach should work.

Comment: $P(N(3)=2)=e^{-3\lambda}\frac{(3\lambda)^2}{2!}$, $P(N(1)=0)=e^{-\lambda}$, $P(N(5)=4)=e^{-5\lambda}\frac{(5\lambda)^4}{4!}$

Comment: OK, that was not helpful. What is $P(N(3)=2|N(1)=0)$? What is $P(N(5)=4|N(1)=0)$? What is $P(N(5)=4|N(3)=2)$?

Comment: I am aiming for a very basic property of Poisson processes.

Comment: $P(N(3)=2\mid N(1)=0)=\frac{P(N(3)=2)P(N(1)=0)}{P(N(1)=0)}$ and so on..

Comment: The course literature I use is very abstract, thus I may seem to look very begginer

Comment: No, the events $\{N(3)=2\}$ and $\{N(1)=0\}$ are not independent.

Comment: You need to be careful here. The Poisson process gives probabilities for observing a certain number of events in a time interval. Rather than what you have in the question, the probability mass function for the Poisson process is $p(N(t+\tau) - N(t) = k\;|\;\lambda) = e^{-\lambda\tau}(\lambda\tau)^k / k!$

Comment: Carl, okay, so this is the increments right? But in what way are these event dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial property of Poisson processes that you should have mentioned in the comments since @LutzL prodded you for it (and even in the question itself) is *the independence of the increments*, that is, the fact that the number of events of the process in disjoint intervals are independent.

Here, three disjoint intervals are involved, namely $(0,1]$, $(1,3]$ and $[3,5]$, hence one should try to write down everything in terms of $X=N(1)$, $Y=N(3)-N(1)$ and $Z=N(5)-N(3)$. Then, $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are Poisson with the parameters you know and *independent*, and you are interested in the events
$$
B=[N(1)=0,N(5)=4]=[X=0,Y+Z=4],
$$
and
$$
A=[N(1)=0,N(3)=2,N(5)=4]=[X=0,Y=2,Z=2].
$$
Thus, 
$$
P[B]=p_\lambda(0)p_{4\lambda}(4),\qquad P[A]=p_\lambda(0)p_{2\lambda}(2)p_{2\lambda}(2),
$$
where $p_\mu(n)$ denotes the probabiolity that a Poisson random variable with parameter $\mu$ is $n$.
Thus, you are looking for
$$
\frac{P[A]}{P[B]}=\frac{p_\lambda(0)p_{2\lambda}(2)p_{2\lambda}(2)}{p_\lambda(0)p_{4\lambda}(4)}.
$$
If you compute this ratio, you should see that $\lambda$ disappears...